# Django query question

Tags: python, html, django, models

I have a view & template which displays a list of types of items. This is ok, but instead of displaying all different the types of items for that client. What I want to do is display the list of types *individually*.

For example, if an Item has a type stored say "General". I want to display all items that has a type only called "General".

Views

```
   def client_summary(request, client_id):
        client = None
        items = None
    try:
        client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id)
        items = client.storageitem_set.all()
        total_items = items.count()
        except:
            return HttpResponse(reverse(return_clients))
        return render_to_response('client_summary.html', {'items':items, 'total_items':total_items, 'client':client}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Template

```
Summary for {{client.name}}
Total Number of Items: {{total_items}}
{%for item in items}
        {{item.type}}
{%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `client.storageitem_set.filter(type=YOUR_TYPE):

```
def client_summary(request, client_id):
    client = None
    items = None
    try:
        client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id)
        items = client.storageitem_set.filter(type="General")
        total_items = items.count()
        except:
           return HttpResponse(reverse(return_clients))
        return render_to_response('client_summary.html', {'items':items, 'total_items':total_items, 'client':client}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

docs: [Following relationships backwards](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Comment: that will only allow for one type though? I think he wants to list all the types that may exist

Comment: yes, but he can use an __in query, the idea is to read the docs :)

Comment: Actually this is what I want. This does work. The problem is that each type has a number. So it would complain that the value is not an interger.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you want to [regroup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) on type.